# My return statement returns empty string but printing it returns correct value

Tags: python

```
def selection(alist):
    sorted_list = []
    while alist:
        minimum = alist.pop(alist.index(min(alist)))
        sorted_list.append(minimum)
    print(sorted_list)
    return sorted_list

a = [54,35,23,86,3546,87,43,7,2]
selection(a)
print(selection(a))
```

Comment: Can you update your indentation to match what you're executing? It's hard to tell whether it was entered incorrectly, or if the indentation is part of them problem.

Comment: Because you're calling your function twice, by the time of the second call, `a` is already empty. Either create a copy of `a` for each function call, or call `section` only once.

Comment: You are mutating the list be sequentially `pop`ing the minimum elements. This is **incredibly** inefficient, btw, but anyway, it is not exactly clear what problem you are describing, but definitely, the second time you call `selection(a)` will not work because `a` will be an empty list.

Comment: updated it thanks @ryachza

Comment: Thank you guys i am new to programming, 1 month old, what would be a better implentation @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: @sir3n.sn there is a *huge* amount of information on sorting algorithms. I suggest you do some reading. But if you are actually just trying to sort something, and not merely play around with sorting algorithms, then just use `my_list.sort()` or `sorted(my_list)`. The former sorts inplace, and the latter returns a new list. The underlying algorithm is timsort, an adaptive merge-sort implemented in C that is going to be faster than anything you cook-up in pure Python, pretty much guaranteed.

Comment: "empty string"? There is no string anywhere.

Comment: @sir3n.sn Python has a built-in `sorted` function - I would look that up, and familiarize yourself with the options like `reverse` and `key`. If you're trying to implement it yourself, you can look up "sorting algorithms" - there are many. "quicksort" or "mergesort" would probably be most reasonable in terms of simplicity and performance.

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning the function call to a variable. This will allow you to store the data and recall it when needed.

```
def selection(alist):
    sorted_list = []
    while alist:
        minimum = alist.pop(alist.index(min(alist)))
        sorted_list.append(minimum)
    print(sorted_list)
    return sorted_list

a = [54,35,23,86,3546,87,43,7,2]
value = selection(a)
print(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because `selection` is popping out all the values of `a`. If you want to keep `a` as it is you should clone it to a temporary array and only manipulate this array.

```
def selection(alist):
    temp = list(alist)
    sorted_list = []
    while temp:
        minimum = temp.pop(temp.index(min(temp)))
        sorted_list.append(minimum)
    return sorted_list
```

Then `a` stays the same:

```
>>> selection(a)
[2, 7, 23, 35, 43, 54, 86, 87, 3546]
>>> print(selection(a))
[2, 7, 23, 35, 43, 54, 86, 87, 3546]
>>> a
[54, 35, 23, 86, 3546, 87, 43, 7, 2]
```

If your goal is only to sort this array and you don't care for not writing the sorting algorithm by yourslef, it would probably be a better idea (and much more efficient) to use the builtin [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) function of python:

```
>>> a = [54,35,23,86,3546,87,43,7,2]
>>> sorted(a)
[2, 7, 23, 35, 43, 54, 86, 87, 3546]
>>> a
[54, 35, 23, 86, 3546, 87, 43, 7, 2]
```

If you want to permanently sort `a` use `a.sort()`:

```
>>> a = [54,35,23,86,3546,87,43,7,2]
>>> a.sort()
>>> a
[2, 7, 23, 35, 43, 54, 86, 87, 3546]
```

Comment: Woops, bad indention - fixed :) Thanks!